# Not able to open an new URL using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

When trying to open and new url using .get() method of FirefoxDriver using selenium new url is not getting opened instead I ma getting an blank screen with below exception.

My Firefox version is 27
Selenium jars of version "selenium-2.39.0"
I am getting same exception in case of ChromeDriver and IRDriver

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: f.QueryInterface is  not a function
Command duration or timeout: 50 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'ANKUR-PC', ip: '169.254.81.96', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Session ID: 3e90ea0a-fce7-44c4-9df0-15231046ae45
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=27.0.1}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:276)
    at Selenium.main(Selenium.java:14)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: f.QueryInterface is not a function
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'ANKUR-PC', ip: '169.254.81.96', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.get(file:///C:/Users/ANKUR/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1797840660297297360webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8720)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/ANKUR/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1797840660297297360webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/ANKUR/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1797840660297297360webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10836)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/ANKUR/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1797840660297297360webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10778)
```

The code which I am using is:

```
    Proxy prox = new Proxy();
    prox.setAutodetect(true);

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("browser", "firefox");
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY,prox);
    FirefoxDriver f= new FirefoxDriver(cap);

    f.get("www.google.com");
```

Comment: Please show your code if you want an answer.

Comment: Barak manos I have added the code. I have also tried without using proxy class and DesiredCapabilities class but it still does not work.

Comment: In last command, try  `f.get("http://www.google.com");`

Answer (score 4):

Please use the `http` prefix before url. Rewrite the line as `f.get("http://www.google.com");`. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

**Method get requires the protocol as part of the URL.**

Change:

```
String baseurl = "www.google.com";
```

To:

```
String baseurl = "http://www.google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 FirefoxProfile ff = new FirefoxProfile();
 FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla       Firefox\\firefox.exe"));
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary,ff);
 driver.get(URL);
```

Answer (score -2):

Please uninstall ur latest version of firefox and use version like firefox 22 becoz I too faced the same issue